# How are the isometries $h:(\mathbb{R}^n,||\cdot||_p)\longrightarrow(\mathbb{R}^n,||\cdot||_p)\;$?

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry

An *isometry* of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a function $h:\mathbb{R}^n\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ that preserves the distance between vectors:

$$||h(x)-h(y)||_p=||x-y||_p\;\;, \;\;p\ge1$$

for all $x$ and $y$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, where $||(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)||_p=(x_1^p+x_2^p+\cdots+x_n^p)^{\frac{1}{p}}$

If $p=2$ $\Longrightarrow$ $h(x)=A\cdot x+a$ , where $A$ is a ortogonal matrix

If $p\neq2$ how are the isometries $h$ ?

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: You get at least the translations, permutations of coordinates and the coordinate reflections (putting minus signs on some of the coordinates), and all composites of these. From the pictures I have in mind it seems these transformations may exhaust the possibilities, at the very least the affine isometries when $p\neq 2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By [Mazur-Ulam theorem](https://web.archive.org/web/20180516125105/http://www.helsinki.fi:80/%7Ejvaisala/mazurulam.pdf) the desired isomety is composition of shift and some isometric linear operator. So further we can assume that $h$ is a linear isometry. By [Lamperty's characterization](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/pacific-journal-of-mathematics/volume-8/issue-3/On-the-isometries-of-certain-function-spaces/pjm/1103039892.full) of isometries of $L_p$ spaces we know that linear isometries on $\mathbb{R}^n_p$ maps $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ to $(s_1 x_{\sigma(1)},\ldots,s_nx_{\sigma(n)})$, where $|s_1|=\ldots=|s_n|=1$ and $\sigma\in \mathfrak{S}_n$

Comment: Crediting Lamperti alone seems a bit unfair. Banach already did the cases $\ell_p$ and $L_p[0,1]$ in his book. Of course, this includes the simple case of finite-dimensional $\ell_p$-spaces. Lamperti's contribution is to extend that result to all measure spaces. Moreover, you need to allow permutations of the coordinates, not only multiplication by $\pm 1$.

Comment: There is a lot of unfair thing in this world. Why are you so confident that Banach envented normed spaces may be that was some one else? As for perrmutations, I made corrections. Thank you!

Comment: ?$\phantom{}{}{}$

Comment: Well, that was trolling-like joke